# Make a field optional in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use paperclip to attach an avatar to users, which works fine but when a new user attempts to register it complains about the avatar bieng too small and not of the right type.

This is how i validate my avatars:

```
validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

This is the error i get when i try to register.

```
There were problems with the following fields:

* Avatar file size file size must be between 0 and 1048576 bytes.
* Avatar content type is not included in the list
```

is there anyway to make it so that avatar can be blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is gonna work but try:

```
validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes, :if => avatar_changed?
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], :if => avatar_changed?
```

Comment: I used ":unless => :new_user?" and wrote a function that returns true/false which seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use paperclip, but in general in Rails you can add condition to decide if validations should be run.

```
validates_attachment_size :avatar, 
  :less_than => 1.megabytes, 
  :unless => "avatar.blank?"
```

You should add similar condition to all validations that affects avatar. If you want know more take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).

Answer (score 0):

It's more like:

`validates_attachment_size :avatar, 
  :less_than => 1.megabytes, 
  :unless => "avatar_content_type.blank?"`