# validates_attachment for optional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip-validation

I have an uload field which is optional, it can be left empty. But when it is is used, I want to validate the size and content of the attachment. So I use this validation in the model:

```
validates_attachment :attachment, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }
```

This works when there is an attachment, but fails when it is left empty. How can I make sure it only validates when there is an attached file?

The solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957752/make-a-field-optional-in-rails) are not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided is giving you what I would suggest - using the `if:` argument

--

**`if:`**

[Using `if:` in your validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) basically allows you to determine conditions on which the validator will fire. I see from the link, the guys are using `if: :avatar_changed?`

The problem you've likely encountered is you can either use a `Proc` or `instance method` to determine the condition; and as these guys are using a method on `avatar` (albeit an inbuilt one), it's not likely going to yield the result you want.

I would do this:

```
validates_attachment :attachment, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }, if: Proc.new {|a| a.attachment.present? }
```

This basically determines if the `attachment` object is present, providing either `true` or `false` to the validation

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :small => "200x200>" }
validates_attachment :attachment,
    :size => { :in => 0..500.kiobytes },
    :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/ }
```

its working on my app. except i have set a default attachment in case user chooses not to upload one.