# how to make an optional attachment in rails using paperclip, angular js, ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a "payment" form that has a file attachment for upload the receipt_img, i'm using paperclip, angular.js in frontend and ng-file-upload plugin..

everything works fine if the attachment is filled,

but i want to make this attachment as an optional attachment, 
i have tried many ways in the other same question in this stackoverflow

[same-question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030256/validates-attachment-for-optional-field), [same-question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957752/make-a-field-optional-in-rails)

but no one works on my form, there's always show the error

```
No handler found for null

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 119ms (Views: 15.4ms | ActiveRecord: 41.7ms)
```

the things i want to ask are,

is there any method in ng-file-upload plugin that make an attachment is ruquired, so it wouldn't work if empety?

is there any way how to solve it ?

here's my paperclip for receipt image :

```
has_attached_file :receipt_img, dependent: :destroy
validates_attachment :receipt_img, :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }, :size => { :in => 0..2.megabytes }
```

and it's my payment.coffee :

```
Sprangular.service "Payment", ($http, $q, _, Env, Account, Cart, Flash, Upload) ->



service =
    confirmPaymentBankTransfer: (order, payment, bankTransfer) ->

  url = Spree.mountedAt() + "/api/orders/#{order.number}/payments/#{payment.id}"

  bankTransfer.receipt_img.upload = Upload.upload
    url: url
    method: 'PUT'
    headers:
      'X-Spree-Order-Token': order.token
    data:
      payment:
        receipt_img: bankTransfer.receipt_img
        bank_name: bankTransfer.bank_name
        deposited_on: bankTransfer.deposited_on
        account_name: bankTransfer.account_name
        account_no: bankTransfer.account_no
        transaction_reference_no: bankTransfer.transaction_reference_no
        our_bank_name: bankTransfer.our_bank_name

  # $http.put(url, $.param(params), config)
  #   .success (response) ->
  #     Flash.success 'app.account_updated'
  #   .error (response) ->
  #     Flash.error 'app.account_update_failed'
service
```

thanks,

**edit add controller.coffee**

```
'use strict'

class Sprangular.BankTransfer
  Validity.define @,
    deposited_on: 'required'
    bank_name: 'required'
    account_no: 'required'
    transaction_reference_no: 'required'
    our_bank_name: 'required'

  constructor: (deposited_on=null, bank_name=null, account_name=null, account_no=null, transaction_reference_no=null, our_bank_name=null, receipt_img=null) ->
    @deposited_on = deposited_on
    @bank_name = bank_name
    @account_name = account_name
    @account_no = account_no
    @transaction_reference_no = transaction_reference_no
    @our_bank_name = our_bank_name
    @receipt_img = receipt_img

  init: ->
    @id = @id
    @deposited_on = @deposited_on
    @bank_name = @bank_name
    @account_name = @account_name
    @account_no = @account_no
    @transaction_reference_no = @transaction_reference_no
    @our_bank_name = @our_bank_name
    @receipt_img = @receipt_img

  same: (other) ->
    @id == other.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh Alhamdulillah god,
it's solved by myself after headche for a day..

after tried many ways of references, but no one worked at all,
i'm solved it  by creating a condition in my service (payment.coffee), so the service look like this :

```
Sprangular.service "Payment", ($http, $q, _, Env, Account, Cart, Flash, Upload) ->

  service =

confirmPaymentBankTransfer: (order, payment, bankTransfer) ->
  if bankTransfer.receipt_img is null
    params =
      payment:
        bank_name: bankTransfer.bank_name
        deposited_on: bankTransfer.deposited_on
        account_name: bankTransfer.account_name
        account_no: bankTransfer.account_no
        transaction_reference_no: bankTransfer.transaction_reference_no

    config =
      ignoreLoadingIndicator: true
      headers:
        'X-Spree-Order-Token': order.token

    url = Spree.mountedAt() + "/api/orders/#{order.number}/payments/#{payment.id}"

    $http.put(url, $.param(params), config)
      .success (response) ->
        Flash.success 'app.account_updated'
      .error (response) ->
        Flash.error 'app.account_update_failed'

  else
    url = Spree.mountedAt() + "/api/orders/#{order.number}/payments/#{payment.id}"

    bankTransfer.receipt_img.upload = Upload.upload
      url: url
      method: 'PUT'
      headers:
        'X-Spree-Order-Token': order.token
      data:
        payment:
          receipt_img: bankTransfer.receipt_img
          bank_name: bankTransfer.bank_name
          deposited_on: bankTransfer.deposited_on
          account_name: bankTransfer.account_name
          account_no: bankTransfer.account_no
          transaction_reference_no: bankTransfer.transaction_reference_no
          our_bank_name: bankTransfer.our_bank_name  

    # $http.put(url, $.param(params), config)
    #   .success (response) ->
    #     Flash.success 'app.account_updated'
    #   .error (response) ->
    #     Flash.error 'app.account_update_failed'

  service
```

so i put the if else condition on the function,.
it's look a little dirty, but it's work fine for me..

thx for help..

Answer (score 0):

`validates_attachment` is requiring that the attachment be present and meet all the specifications you declare. If you want the attachment to be optional, use `allow_nil`:

```
validates_attachment :receipt_img,
  :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
  :size => { :in => 0..2.megabytes },
  :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: where should i declare that ?

is it like this ?

validates_attachment :receipt_img, :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }, :size => { :in => 0..2.megabytes }, allow_nil:true

Comment: Yep, that's the spot

Comment: no, it's still doesn't work,

the error keep shown 



"No handler found for null

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 119ms (Views: 15.4ms | ActiveRecord: 41.7ms)"

Comment: i've edit the question, i add the controller, maybe can be more help,.